# Hibernate "Could not parse mapping document from resource"

Tags: hibernate, grails

I've a problem in my first grails application. I tried to modify my hibernate files a hundred times, but I still get this exception:

```
    | Error 2012-12-03 13:24:23,190 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps:
 Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org
.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve
 reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframewor
k.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed;
 nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource user.hbm.xml
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exceptio
n is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot
 resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.spring
framework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method
 failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource user.
hbm.xml
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 's
essionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanC
reationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource user.hbm.xml
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; neste
d exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource user.hbm.xml
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource user.hbm.xml
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping santrain.User
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

User.groovy:

```
package test

class User {

    Integer id
    String f1
    String f2

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    '-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN'
    'http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd'>

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <mapping resource='user.hbm.xml'/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

EDIT: When I write       --> everything works, so the error must be anywhere in user.hbm.xml...

user.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="test">
    <class name="test.User" table="test_user">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer" />
        <property column="f1" name="f1" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="f2" name="f2" type="java.lang.String" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "testuser"
    password = "testpass"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" 
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?autoreconnect=true"
        }
    }
...
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Where are the hibernate configuration files?  [They should be in `grails-app/conf/hibernate`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html).

Comment: Yes, both files are located in grails-app/conf/hibernate.

Comment: `DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping santrain.User` I think that's your problem. Do you put your class in the domains folder?

Comment: Yes, User.groovy is located in domain/test/User.groovy.

Comment: Grails will map all in domain for you, why you declared this hibernate mapping?

Comment: Because I wanted to name the tables manually. For example: Save User.groovy in Table groovy_user.

Comment: You can do that with `static mapping = { table 'groovy_user' }` in the domain class.  There's [lots of other things](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.1/guide/GORM.html#ormdsl) you can configure in the `mapping` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all hibernate-mappings and used 
    static mapping = { table 'groovy_user' }
Thanks to Ian Roberts!